# How to judge whether it is a new day in an iOS project?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIView ,I want it to display in a new day.For example,today I launch my app,and that UIView comes to my view,but after this,I can't see that UIView until tomorrow.

So I want to know how to judge whether it is a new day to display the UIView?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to register for the `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(timeChange) name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Then in the `timeChange` method (or whatever you call it) update your view.

Don't forget to unregister:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:nil];
```

This notification is sent at midnight, if the user changes the time on their device, or the timezone changes. If your app is in the background when the change happens, it will get notified when the app returns to the foreground.

Comment: When the Time changes,I want the app to display a viewController in front of the view of the app displayed,and it sounds like the UIAlertView?Is that possible?

Comment: You can perform any action you went when you get the time change notification. Keep in mind that when you get the notification, it could be 5 minutes earlier (if the user change the time on your iOS device), it could be the next day (midnight), or it could be a week later (if the app has been in the background for several days).

Comment: What happens if you have your app closed. You will miss the notification when the app is opened after midnight ?

Comment: @Kobe if your app was in the background you will still get the notification when your app enters the foreground.

Comment: Yeah, but lets say your app is closed, doesn't appear in the app switcher. Do you need to remember the date when app is closed and then read the date when is open and compare it ? Is that the way to go ?

Comment: @Kobe If your app isn't running then of course it doesn't get the notification. Simply get the current date when your app starts up the next time.

Comment: @rmaddy how do I know if I want to get notified daily  even if I have not opened my app since a number of  days ago